# Error lines in flutter AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: flutter, android-manifest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwJ4i.png)
Hello, there are a few lines with errors in AndroidManifest.xml as shown in the picture, I couldn't find what the problem is. Please help if anyone encounters this problem.

I created a new project but the error persist

Comment: ignore the errors in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Tell me when you try to run flutter app then what error come?

Comment: Click `Open for Editing in Android Studio` and you won't see any error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This not a part of error because these errors show only that time when you open flutter project, when you open particular **Android Folder** in android then these error not show.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me was **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.**